# Extract all words from a given sentence and print them along with their consonant counts

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have to take a sentence as an input, extract each word from it one by one and print their respective consonant counts with them. This is the code I am using:

```
for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        count=0; word="";
        if(sentence.charAt(i)!=' ')
        {
            word+=sentence.charAt(i);
        }
        else
        {
            for(int j=0;j<word.length();j++)
            {
                ch=word.charAt(i);
                if (ch!='A'&&ch!='E'&&ch!='I'&&ch!='E'&&ch!='O'&&ch!='U')
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }}
            System.out.print(word+"\t"+count);}
```

I have been trying to debug this and I always get a variety of outputs I don't require. 
The two major problem I am facing are:

1. How to extract a word from a sentence WITHOUT using Scanner or other classes and only using basic loops
2. How to list the accurate consonant count properly formatted into a table form

Furthermore, I intend to add the extracted word to a String array at an index equal to its consonant count.

```
StringArr[count]=" "+word;
```

I am adding the space there to make way if more than two words have the same consonant count.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S.- I am a rookie at this so please feel free to point out any contextual errors I may have noted.

Comment: Is this a Java or JavaScript issue? For JavaScript, you don't need a loop to break a sentence apart. Just use `var words = sentence.split(" ");`. This will give you an array of each word. From there, you can loop through that array, word by word and on each word, you can then test for consonants.

Comment: any substitute for `var` in Javascript?

Comment: There is `let` for block scoping and `const` for constants.

Comment: [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.io)

Comment: Is this Java or Javascript?

Comment: If you want to use a loop to split the sentence into words, you're almost there.  Your first big problem is that you're setting `word = ""` in the wrong place.  You're doing it on _every_ iteration--you can't build up a word like that if you keep clearing it.  Also, `"/t"` is wrong if you want a tab--should be `"\t"`.

Comment: Scott Marcus did you mean `String words[]=sentence.split(" ");`?

Comment: This is Java, guys.

Comment: Java could not be more different than JavaScript...why can so many people not understand that...

Comment: @PrometheusWithoutMind Edit your tags

Comment: @PrometheusWithoutMind Are you allowed to use [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))? That would be the easiest way to split a string into its words.

Comment: I can't, though I admit I created code with that technique and the program works as required. I am only allowed to use loops.

Answer (score 2):

If you approach the problem using the simplest code you can, you'll have less code, which is (usually) easier the understand and thus has less bugs.

The number of consonants is simply the length with non-consonants removed:

```
int count = str.replaceAll("(?i)[^b-df-hj-np-tv-z]", "").length();
```

Regex explanation:

- `(?i)` means ignore case
- `[^...]` is a *negated character class*, ie any char not in the list
- `b-d` means chars in the range `b` to `d` (inclusive)
- etc for other character ranges

This code caters for edge cases too, whereas your code has a bug; it counts all "non vowels" as a consonant, but that would count apostrophes too. Consider that `"can't"` has 3 consonants.

Using the above, plus `split()` to get "words":

```
for (String word : sentence.split("\\s+")) {
    int count = str.replaceAll("(?i)[^b-df-hj-np-tv-z]", "").length();
    System.out.println(word + '\t' + count);
}
```

Employ a stream and in-line the count, and you can do it in 1 statement:

```
Arrays.stream(sentence.split("\\s+"))
  .forEach(w -> System.out.println(w + '\t' +
     w.replaceAll("(?i)[^b-df-hj-np-tv-z]", "").length());
```

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method to get the words and then use printf to format the string:

```
    for (String word: sentence.split(" ")) {
        System.out.printf("%10s: %d\n", word, getConsonantCount(word));
    }
```

(For more info on formatting, checkout [this cheatsheet](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet) for printf)
Now, the core method of the program `getConsonantCount()` could be implemented as:

```
public static int getConsonantCount(String word) {

    word = word.toLowerCase();
    int consonantCnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char ch = word.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            if (vowels.indexOf(ch) == -1) {
                consonantCnt++;
            }   
        }   
    }   
    return consonantCnt;
}
```

Basically, we first verify the character is a letter and then check whether it is a vowel or not by trying to get its index in the string `vowels`. Increment the counter if it is not a vowel (hence a consonant).

```
public static String vowels = "aeiou";
```

---

## The manual approach (without String.split())

The way you are trying to do it is a valid approach. But the problem is that you are resetting `count` and `word` for each new character.

So, consider the question: where should we reset those variables?

When we have found a word and processed it. It needs to be done in the *else* block. Also, print out the words and count there as well. (Right now, you are printing after processing each character).

```
      for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isLetter(sentence.charAt(i))) {
            word += sentence.charAt(i);
        }
        else if(sentence.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            for(int j=0;j<word.length();j++) {
                ch = Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(j));
                if (ch !='A' && ch != 'E' && ch != 'I' && ch!= 'E' && ch != 'O' && ch != 'U') {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("%10s: %d\n", word, count);
            count = 0;
            word ="";
        }
    }
```

This wouldn't pick up the last word. One solution could be to add a *space* to the end of the sentence beforehand.

Instead of building a word and then processing it when you encounter a *space*, you could also just count the consonants as you go.

```
    count = 0;
    int start = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(sentence.charAt(i))) {
            ch = Character.toUpperCase(sentence.charAt(i));
            if (ch != 'A' && ch != 'E' && ch != 'I' && ch != 'E' && ch != 'O' && ch != 'U') {
                count++;
            }
        } else if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            System.out.printf("%10s: %d\n", sentence.substring(start, i), count);
            start = i + 1;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

Here, the variable `start` keeps track of the start of the current word.

As for the `stringArray` variable, consider making it a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).